# How to refactor a class in C++ to make a certain function const?

Tags: c++, oop, constants

I have a class which looks something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  // some stuff omitted

  /*** 
    A function which, in itself, is constant and doesn't change the class
  ***/
  void myFunction( void ) const;
private:
  /***
    If loaded is true, then internal resources are loaded
  ***/
  boolean loaded;
};
```

Because I designed my class this way I am forced to do this:

```
MyClass :: myFunction( void ) const
{
  if( !loaded )
  {
     // do something here

     loaded = true; /** <-- this violates const **/
  }

  // carry out some computation
}
```

Because I need to set *loaded* flag the function now violates *const* qualifier.

I have a lot of code that stores constant objects and it will be time consuming to go round and change them to non-const. Moreover, this will be slightly hacky since I really want the objects to be const.

What is the best way to refactor my class in order to keep *myFunction* constant?

P.S. The resources guarded by *loaded* are required only for several functions and therefore loading them in advance is not a very good solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the **mutable** keyword.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  void myFunction( void ) const;
private:
  mutable boolean loaded;
};
```

This says that the loaded member should be treated as being logically const but that physically it may change.

Comment: Oh my... Thank you. I knew there was an embarassingly easy solution to this.

Comment: +1: Never knew this but needed it many times. (I used slow pointer-solution [bool *loaded => pointer never changes but value behind pointer can] or dirty cast solution.